# can't read arp packets in c

Tags: c, sockets, raw-sockets

i have the following simple code to capture all the arp packet sent to my device but it doesn't print anything

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h>

int main(){
        int sock;
        char recvbuf[2048];
        if((sock=socket(PF_PACKET,SOCK_DGRAM,htons(ETH_P_ARP)))==-1){
                perror("socket error");
                return -1;
        }
        for(;;){
                if(recvfrom(sock,recvbuf,sizeof(recvbuf),0,NULL,NULL)==-1){
                        perror("recvfrom error");
                }
                struct ether_header *e;
                e=(struct ether_header *)recvbuf;
                printf("arp from :%s\n",e->ether_shost);
        }
}
```

the output is like:

```
arp from :
arp from :
arp from :
arp from :
arp from :
```

Comment: `e->ether_shost` is a sequence of bytes, not ascii characters (so %s is not appropriate). try to display each of them in hex.

Comment: `ether_shost` isn't a string, it's the ethernet address in byte form.

Comment: i don't understand it is array of bytes isn't that same as string

Comment: oh ok i get it now i have to print each byte separately in hex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string, to be printed with `%s`, is a sequence of *characters* terminated with the special null-terminator character `'\0'`.

The data in `e->ether_shost` is a series of six bytes, not characters, not null-terminated, and you need to print them one by one as small integers (usually in hexadecimal notation):

```
printf("%02hhx:%02hhx:%02hhx:%02hhx:%02hhx:%02hhx\n",
    e->ether_shost[0], e->ether_shost[1], e->ether_shost[2],
    e->ether_shost[3], e->ether_shost[4], e->ether_shost[5]);
```

For an explanation of the format used, see e.g. [this `printf` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).